# Can't access SQL Server file in the server machine

Tags: sql-server, wcf, iis

I setup the my WCF service on server machine.

The server OS is Windows 2008 with SQL Server 2008 Express.

I am trying to access to my SQL Server (mdf) file to read data using LINQ to SQL.

I see that the DataContext is OK - but when I try to get information that in one of the table I get an exception

> Failed to generate a user instance of
>   SQL Server due to failure in
>   retrieving the user's local
>   application data path. Please make
>   sure the user has a local user profile
>   on the computer. The connection will
>   be closed.

I don't know what i need to define or change in the IIS 7.5 that I'm using in the server side.

Thanks for any help.

**Update:** the connection to the database file is fine - but getting information from table is thru an exception. The connection string is:

```
Data Source=.;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ServiceData.mdf;
  Integrated Security=SSPI;User Instance=True
```

Comment: Can you include your connection string?

Comment: The connection to the database file is fine - but getting information from table is thru an exception. the connection string :    Data Source=.;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ServiceData.mdf;Integrated Security=SSPI;User Instance=True

Comment: please don't put stuff like this in the comments!! Really hard to read. Instead: **update** your original post by **editing** it to provide additional info!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have a server, why don't you just attach the MDF to the SQL Server (Express) running, and then use it like a normal database on your server?

After you do this, use a connection string like:

```
server=Server\SQLExpress;Database=YourDatabaseName;Integrated Security=SSPI
```

I never quite liked the `AttachDbFileName=` and `User Instance` approach - seems like a (unreliable) hack to me, which really doesn't make sense if you're running on a server machine.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you are getting this error message is because your code is in the security context of a user that has never logged on to the server. The user therefore does not have a profile and you therefore get an error when the code attempts to write to a non-existant profile.

You could use marc_s's approach or you could run as a user that has a profile.

Comment: The server is win 2008 - What is marc_s's approach ? If the user that try to get the information is using WCF web service to get the information - how can he loggin the system ?