# Database access problem after site hosted

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have hosted a website.  The dataconnection I am using is (web.config file)

**It works fine on the localhost** but when run over the internet, it gives error that access to databse is not possible. (please visit www.ezitek.somee.com for detailed error)
I think I need to change the connection string, but I do not know what to do.

When hosted, my database is in App_Data folder of my solution, which has been uploaded as it is.

My host has given me the following detail:

Website local path: d:\DZHosts\LocalUser\fsehgal\www.ezitek.somee.com
Protected local path:   d:\DZHosts\LocalUser\fsehgal\Protected.ezitek.somee.com

Please advise what to do to avoid this error.

Thank you very much.
With best regards,
Furqan

Answer (score 0):

try replacing your AttachDBFilename in your connection with something similar to this

```
AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\DB.mdf;
```

Comment: maybe the database file is protected against modification or writing?

Comment: check this [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369959/unable-to-connect-to-sql-database-in-appdata-when-deployed-to-web-server